# Batch stops after chrome opens on kiosk

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I'm trying to automate the login on a kiosk machine..

I'm using a batch file to start chrome in kiosk mode and then I need it to open a exe file that will run some macro to login..

The problem is my script don't do anything after it opens chrome.. If I close chrome the script will continue with timeout?

Why do chrome "pause" the script until i close it and the script continue with the TIMEOUT?

My batch file:

```
chcp 1252
@echo off
cls

echo Step 1 of 5: Venter på computeren er klar

"C:\windows\system32\ping" -n 5 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 >NUL

echo Step 2 of 5: Tester netværk

"C:\windows\system32\ping" -n 5 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 >NUL

echo Step 3 of 5: Åbner Chrome i Kiosk mode

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome --kiosk --app=https://kiosk-page.com

echo Step 4 of 5: Venter på Chrome er klar

TIMEOUT /T 10

echo Step 5 of 5: Starter macro login

start /d "C:\Kiosk-Web\" KioskWebLogin.exe

exit
```

I don't know much about using batch files, so the above script is build from what ever i could find that worked..

Can anyone tell me why this breaks?

Comment: Why use `Ping` to perform a task you've already shown that you know how to do using `Timeout`? Similarly, you've already shown that you know about the `Start` command, so try to see what happens if you use it elsewhere. _(hint: add `Start "" ` in front of your `Chrome` command line)_.

Comment: Ahh..Adding start to chrome looks do the trick..
Fund the ping stuff from another sample and thought it would be a good way to make sure the computer is ready and online.. The timeout is to make sure the slow ass kiosk pc has chrome ready before the macro stuff begins..

But thank you.

Comment: Your `Ping` commands simply perform a timeout of 4-5 seconds. I'm glad that the `Start` command worked for you I'll post an answer, based on my comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example based on your script and my comments:

```bat
@Echo Off
ChCp 1252
ClS
Echo Step 1 of 3: Åbner Chrome i Kiosk mode
Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome --kiosk --app=https://kiosk-page.com
Echo Step 2 of 3: Venter på Chrome er klar
Timeout 5 /NoBreak >Nul
Echo Step 3 of 3: Starter macro login
Start "" /D "C:\Kiosk-Web" KioskWebLogin.exe
Exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you.. The kiosk works perfectly with the script.